# Android SearchView not removed on menu clear

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-menu

I am using app compat activity. I have a fragment where I added a search view in the MenuItemCompat. Now when I am opening another Fragment within the same container I can still see the Search View when clicking on the action bar Menu item. I have added the following

```
 @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

        menu.clear();

        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

//        MenuItemCompat.setActionView(menu.getItem(1), null);

        //SearchView searchView =View.findViewById(R.id.searchViewId);

//       MenuItemCompat.collapseActionView(menu.getItem(0));

//        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_add_recipient);
//
//        item.setVisible(false);

        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }
```

in the new fragment but still when clicking on the action bar item the search view is displayed. Any help please.

Comment: your menu_main file will contain searview

Comment: thanks @YounasBangash how to remove it. Right now I am inflating another menu but with different menu item ID and seems working. No More search view

Comment: add another menu which did not contains searchview